# Добавление данных в таблицу используя ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

На форме есть 3 поля, необходимо добавить их в БД без перезагрузки страницы. Форма с скриптом:

```
<form id="myform" action="#" method="post" >
  <div class="trading__buy-row">
    <div class="trading__buy-row-title">Price</div>
    <input type="text" id="price" name="price" class="priceField" onchange=f()>
    <div class="trading__buy-row-title2">BTC</div>
  </div>
  <div class="trading__buy-row">
    <div class="trading__buy-row-title">Amount</div>
    <input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" class="amountField" onchange=f()>
    <div class="trading__buy-row-title2">ETH</div>
  </div>
  <div class="trading__buy-row">
    <div class="trading__buy-row-title">Total</div>
    <input type="text" id="total" name="total" class="totalField" >
    <div class="trading__buy-row-title2">BTC</div>
  </div>
  <div class="trading__buy-text">Trade commission: <span>0.1%</span></div>
  <!--<div class="btn btn--buy" id="sub" >BUY ETH</div> -->
  <input type="submit" value="Buy" class="button">
  <span id="result"></span>
</form>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".button").bind("click", function() {

        var price = jQuery('.priceField').val();
        var amount = jQuery('.amountField').val();
        var total = jQuery('.totalField').val();

        jQuery('.priceField').val('');
        jQuery('.amountField').val('');
        jQuery('.totalField').val('');

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "for_db.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {price:price, amount:amount, total: total}, // Передаем данные для записи
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result) {
                if (result){ 
                    alert ('jQuery подключен и отлично работает!');
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Файл for_db.php

```
<?php
 session_start();
    include_once('db.php');
    if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
        $sesion_id=$_SESSION['userid'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$amount =$_POST['amount'];
$total = $_POST['total'];
}
/** Если нам передали ID то обновляем */
if($price && $amount && $total){
    //вставляем запись в БД
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `ordersbuy` (`id`,`price`,`amount`,`total`) VALUES ('$sesion_id','$price','$amount','$total')");
}
?>
```

Но как только нажимаю на кнопку, поля просто очищаются и ничего не происходит

Comment: А во вкладке network браузера запрос появляется? Если да, какая там ошибка?

Comment: @Diskyp ВОт что выдает, и непонятно почему
:  Undefined variable: price in for_db.phpon line 11

Answer (score -1):

переменные `$price`, `$amount`, `$total` не видны остальной части кода, т.к. объявлены внутри if.

Comment: Вы правы, но как мне тогда получить sesion_id?

Comment: Все, разобрался

Comment: Можно объявить раньше или второй if поместить внутрь первого.